# Who can see the correlation between these numbers

Tags: math, sass, correlation

```
36 => 1.25
34 => 1.3245
24 => 1.88679
22 => 2.06186
```

I'm stuck with these numbers. Who can see a pattern ? The first one is supposed to be exact, and the other are derivates, so they could be rounded (but I don't think so). I suspect there may be variations on the one, so instead of 36:34 there may be a correlation between 35:33 or 37:35 and their associates.

The numbers come from a sass mixin that got lost - the first column was the number of columns in a grid, and the second column the gutter width related to that.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: `y = 45 / x` comes close.

Comment: @JamesKPolk this is a programming question. See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to match, if $X is the left column and $Y is the right column and numbers are rounded to a few digits.

```
$innernumcols=36/$X;
$innernummargins=$innernumcols - 1;
$innerwidth=(100-($innernummargins*1.25)/$innernumcols;
$Y=1.25*100/$innerwidth;
```

which basicly says .. $Y is a reverse percentage of 1.25 depending on $X and related to 36, but indeed with an offset of 1. As a formula, it looks pretty gross.